# Duplicating Calculator Results with Python

Tags: python, math, precision, trigonometry

I don't know how to get Python to behave like my calculator when performing repeating sines.

My Python code:

```
number = float(.565)
pi = float(math.pi)

for j in range(25):
    number = round(math.sin(number*pi), 16)
```

This returns 0.446445551265.

When I do the same operation with my calculator, I get 0.4464454868.

Regardless of the precision I use for `round()`, I can't get the same result as my calculator.

I also tried using the Decimal library, but I didn't get any better results. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that the calculator's result is correct?

Comment: The difference from what your calculator gives you and the program you're running is smaller than `10e-8`. Who cares about the difference? One important thing about floating point is that you're working with a representation of real numbers that is limited in precision. Small differences in the internal representation between your calculator and your computer will be responsible for tiny differences like that (that show up because of cumulative effects).

Comment: Also, pi always has to be rounded at some point, so most likely the source of the discrepancy is that `math.pi` and your calculator's `π` button don't have the same precision.

Comment: Also, when you say "I tried using the Decimal library", what exactly did you try? Are you specifying a higher precision? Are you somehow calculating the sine in some other way than `math.sin` (which is just going to convert your `Decimal`s to `float`s)? Show us the code or we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Finally, why are you calling `round` in the first place? Is it because your calculator rounds all intermediate values to 16 digits? (If so, are you _sure_ it does? Because many calculators actually store more digits than they show…)

Answer (score 2):

Executed in 80 decimal digits precision, the result starts with

0.4464455542636494555603375755720232254414694834911

An error analysis of the algorithm shows that in each step, the previous error is multiplied by about pi (and the cosine of the current point), i.e., about 3, and the current floating point error added as noise. So the margin of error is 3^25 times the machine epsilon.

If one is generous and allows for error cancelation and the actual derivative values, one could also say that the error magnifying factor is about 2^25, i.e., of the 53 bits of the double number mantissa, the 25 last get contaminated, only the first 28 remain somewhat reliable, corresponding to about 7-8 reliable decimal digits, as reflected in the statement of the question.

The pocket calculator has an internal precision that is usually quite larger than the displayed precision, so it is not unexpected to find a more precise result there.